# How to make an Object method an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iife

I've been trying to make an object method an iife, but i've had no luck at all. Is it possible? We are storing all of our functions as methods in an attempt to keep them organised.

I have chosen ONE object & one method to illustrate what I am trying to do, though we have many more.

I'd like to IIFe-fy them because as soon as they initially fire, they have done their job and aren't needed again, with that in mind along with how many methods we will have, to me it makes to iife-fy them.

My code is:

```
let trans = {
    bind_toggle: function(){
        if ($('.tw-o').length != 0) {
            // window open, add toggle
            $('.tw-h').click(function(e){
                $('.tw-b').toggle(599);
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

I'd like trans.bind_toggle to be invoked without having to call it myself... an IIFE, but i've not been able to pull it off. I've tried:

```
let trans = {
    bind_toggle: (function(){
        if ($('.tw-o').length != 0) {
            // window open, add toggle
            $('.tw-h').click(function(e){
                $('.tw-b').toggle(599);
            })();
        }
    } 
}
```

The above returns

> Uncaught TypeError: trans.bind_toggle is not a function

Is it possible to use an IIFE in an object? if so, how would I do it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Should there be a difference in the two blocks of code? Right now they're the same

Comment: I don't  see IIFE that you're here after.

Comment: "Is it possible?" — No, because an IIFE is an expression, not a value. You can set a property to be the return value of an IIFE, which can a function, which would make it a method. It's hard to see what the point of that would be for your code though. You should describe the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than just your attempted solution.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the code, @McVenco. I'd happily call it myself, but we are using a lot of object methods, and  calling them will begin to add up.

Comment: re edit: ```$('.tw-h').click(...)();``` is not an IIFE because that isn't a function expression you've put `()` after.

Comment: [It is possible](https://jsfiddle.net/4r6eyjhm/), but I'm not sure how useful it would be ..? Or did I misundestood the question (it was changed during I made the fiddle)?

Comment: @Teemu, It is simply so I am do not have to manually call every method, it isn't 100% necessary but it's nice to have the option, yanno? When complete, we'll have a large number of methods which need to be run on load, so to me it is tidier to IIFE-fy them- also, that works perfectl. Thank you :)

Comment: Why are they methods in the first place? Your code doesn't make use of `this`

Comment: Well, if you run the code in strict mode, you could check `this` value before returning, if `undefined`, return the function reference, otherwise return something the function should return when called later. I'd still prefer an init method, and called all the methods need in that. Like so: `let obj = {init: function () {/* call all the needed methods */; return this;}}.init();`.

Comment: @Quentin, just to keep them organised :) Refer to my most recent reply as to why I'd like to use an IIFE. Unless I'm mistaken, it makes to do it the way I want to, no? I'm holding them in an object to keep it tidy, then iife-ing them since they're redundant after they initially fire?

Comment: Could you please explain all the things you've put in the comments, in the question itself?

Comment: Not sure we understand the purpose.

Comment: That actually makes much more sense @Teemu. I'm rather new to oo in JS, so I the though of using an init method which contains everything didn't even cross my mind. thank you!!

Comment: Yes, I will update the Q now. Edit: updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead storing one-timer-functions in an object, I'd suggest you to wrap all the code in an IIFE, and then declaring the one-timers in the scope of that function, or make them IIFEs like in the example below. That way they will be decently garbage collected after the IIFE has run. Something like this:

```
(function () {
    (function () {
        // Logig for bind_toggle
    }());
    // All the rest of your code
}());
```

Having all the code in an IIFE you can avoid to declare most of global variables too. If a global is really needed, you can define it as a property of window, like `window.someGlobal = 1`.

Comment: Okay! thank you. My thinking towards it was store all one-fire functions in an object, then the reuseables in another in an attempt to seperate them, though this does the exact same thing, I suppose. Once again, thanks! :)